# <link rel="import"> вставдяет не туда куда нужно, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Пытаюсь использовать `<link rel="import" href="...">` и

```
<script>
  var link = document.querySelector('link[rel=import]');
  var content = link.import.querySelector('#product-card-7');
  document.body.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
</script>
```

Для вставки части другого документа.
Вставка происходит. Но не туда куда нужно, а в конец.

[Вот пример](https://amberroom.rv.ua/experement/product-cart/)

Помогите поставить на нужное место. Если можно, пример готового кода scripts. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сработал такой вариант:
в index.html div в нужном месте

```
<link rel="import" href="import.html">
<div class="ryad-2"></div>
```

в import.html

```
<div id="ryad">контент</div>
<script>
  var me = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
  var post = me.querySelector('#ryad');
  var container = document.querySelector('.ryad-2');
  container.appendChild(post.cloneNode(true));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`appendChild()` всегда вставляет элементы в конец.

```
function insertAfter(newElem, refElem) {
  return refElem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, refElem.nextSibling);
}

let link = document.querySelector('link[rel=import]'),
    content = link.import.querySelector('#product-card-7'),
    referenceElement = document.querySelector('#product-card-6');

insertAfter(content, referenceElement);
```

Стоит заметить, что расположение тега `<script>` не влияет на то, где будет выводиться результат.

Comment: Как все таки должен выглядеть скрипт чтобы вставлять документ например перед .ryad_3 ?